# Symfony Select choices bound to entity boolean fields

Tags: symfony, entity, multi-select

I am trying to couple the options/choices of a multiselect to a field in the database. Is there already support for in Symfony itself?

Relevant Entity fields:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
 */
private $isSpellchecked;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
 */
private $isCompleted;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
 */
private $isEmailed;
```

HTML example:

```
<select multiple>
  <option value="isSpellchecked">Spellchecked</option>
  <option value="isCompleted">Completed</option>
  <option value="isEmailed">Emailed</option>
</select>
```

Of course I will be using [Bootstrap Multiple](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/) for the frontend implementation of the select.
The question is: how to wire the options to the fields without doing it by hand in the controller.

Are I am missing some point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you have to map only one attribute in your entity.

```
/**
 * @var array
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="array", nullable=true)
 */
private $myChoices;

...

public function __construct()
{
    $this->myChoices = [];
}

/**
 * @return array
 */
public function getMyChoices()
{
    return array_unique($this->myChoices);
}

/**
 * @param array $myChoices
 */
public function setMyChoices(array $myChoices)
{
    $this->myChoices = [];

    foreach ($myChoices as $myChoice) {
        $this->addMyChoice($myChoice);
    }

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param string $myChoice
 */
public function addMyChoice($myChoice)
{
    if (!$this->hasMyChoice($myChoice)) {
        $this->myChoices[] = $myChoice;
    }

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param string $myChoice
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function hasMyChoice($myChoice)
{
    return in_array($myChoice, $this->myChoices, true);
}
```

And in your formType, do a classic :

```
->add('myChoices', ChoiceType::class, [
    'choices'  => [
         'Spellchecked',
         'Completed',
         'Emailed',
    ],
    'expanded' => true,
    'multiple' => true,
])
```

Then, your choices are saved in database as array, like this :

```
mychoices field  = a:2:{i:0;s:12:"Spellchecked";i:1;s:7:"Emailed";}
// which is like ['Spellchecked', 'Emailed']
```

And you can retrieve data like this :

```
$isSpellchecked = $MyEntity->hasMyChoice('Spellchecked'); // return true
$isCompleted = $MyEntity->hasMyChoice('Completed'); // return false
```

Comment: Thank you Chuck, however are you sure that with your solution the choices are translated to a database field? And is it possible to do a `getIsEmailed()` on the entity?

Comment: Sorry, I just see that your field has to be "multiple". In this case my response isn't really accurate. I edit it to correspond to your needs.

Comment: Chuck many thanks for your effort and great answer. Definitely the way to go!